# Bold small caps with mathpazo

Tags: small-caps, bold, mathpazo

I was using `tgpagella` but it doesn't have automatic old style numbers without resorting to `fontspec`. I was directed to use `mathpazo` like so:

```
\usepackage[sc,osf]{mathpazo}
```

How do I format `mathpazo` with **BOLD SMALL CAPS**? Here's some of my example code:

```
\textbf{\textsc{question:}}
\textsc{\textbf{question:}}
{\sc{\textbf{question:}}}
{\sc{\bf{question:}}}
```

[image]

```
\textbf{\sc{question:}}
{\bf{\sc{question:}}}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems to me like TeX Gyre Pagella *does* have bold small caps:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tgpagella}
\begin{document}
hello \textbf{hello} \textsc{hello} \textbf{\textsc{hello}}
\end{document}
```

[image: Bold small caps with TeX Gyre Pagella]

I think your problem is that you're using `\sc` when you should be using `\scshape` or `\textsc{...}`. The commands `\bf`, `\it`, `\sc`, etc. are deprecated and should not be used.

Otherwise, if you load `mathpazo` without the `sc` option, you'll get them:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\begin{document}
hello \textbf{hello} \textsc{hello} \textbf{\textsc{hello}}
\end{document}
```

[image: Bold small caps with mathpazo]

They're not real small caps, but sometimes you gotta take what you can get.

Alternatively, (XeLaTeX/LuaLaTeX only) you could buy [Palatino Nova](http://www.linotype.com/615716/palatinonova-family.html), or use Palatino Linotype if you happen to be using Windows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Palatino Linotype}
\begin{document}
hello \textbf{hello} \textsc{hello} \textbf{\textsc{hello}}
\end{document}
```

[image: Bold small caps with Palatino Linotype]

Comment: Hi Will, yes `tgpagella` has bold small caps, but it requires `fontspec` for old style (and thus XeLaTeX, which I don't want to resort to). For `mathpazo`, I need the `[osf]` option for the old style figures. Using `[osf]` enables bold small caps, but the old style figures disappear. I don't want to resort to `\oldstylenums{}` every time I type in numbers. Is there a way to use bold small caps and the automatic old style numbers in `mathpazo` together?

Comment: @Kit, ah, sorry, I missed the part about OSF. In short, then, the answer is no — you need to create a virtual font based on `tgpagella` replacing the numbers over. I'm sure it's not too hard, but I've never done it myself so I can't point you in the right direction. Perhaps look at the `eco` package to see how it does it for the CM fonts.

Comment: Thanks Will. An erratum on my comment above: it should be "NOT using `[osf]` enables..."

Answer (score 1):

A late answer, but since I needed this myself and found a solution, I thought I'd share it. In order to use mathpazo with osf and sc generally and pagella only as a drop-in for bold small caps, do this:

```
% Load pagella first, then mathpazo
\usepackage{tgpagella}
% Note that "osf" includes real small caps, so no sc option needed
\usepackage[osf]{mathpazo}

% Fall back to Pagella for bold small caps. This needs to be done late.
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \DeclareFontShape{T1}{pplj}{b}{sc}{<-> ec-qplb-sc}{}
  \DeclareFontShape{T1}{pplj}{bx}{sc}{<->ssub * qpl/b/sc}{}
}
```

Pagella's small caps look a bit different than mathpazo's (lower x-height), so the solution is not ideal, but I think it's as good as it gets.

[image]