# Old style number, bold small caps, and Palatino

Tags: fonts, bold, small-caps, oldstylenums, mathpazo

I'd like to be able to have all three of the following in my document:

1. the Palatino font
2. bold **and** small caps
3. old-style figures

I'm currently using `mathpazo` with the options `[osf]` to get 1 and 3, but not 2. According to [Bold small caps with mathpazo](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/11605/18228), I'm able to get 1 and 2 (but not 3) if I don't specify the `[osf]` option.

It seems that the `mathpazo` package doesn't really support all of the above three features simultaneously. Does anyone know of a way or an alternative package that implements 1-3?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could try using the recently-released [`newpxtext` and `newpxmath`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/newpx) packages. In the MWE below, issuing the command `\useosf` *after* the math-related packages are loaded enables the use of regular- and bold-weight oldstyle numerals in *text mode*, while lining numerals will be used in math mode. Small caps are available in bold (as well as regular-weight, of course).

[image]

*Update April 2018*: The [`newpxtext` and `newpxmath`](https://ctan.org/pkg/newpx) packages have evolved quite a bit over the past five years. One can still enable oldstyle numerals and small-caps letters by running `\useosf`. According to the packages' user guide, though, the preferred way is to specify the option `osf` while loading the `newpxtext` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newpxtext,newpxmath}
\useosf % old-style figures in text, not in math
\linespread{1.05} % Palatino needs a bit more leading than CM
\begin{document}
0123456789, {\bfseries 0123456789}, {\itshape 0123456789}, {\bfseries\itshape 0123456789}

\textsc{Once upon a time, \dots}
{\bfseries \scshape Once upon a time, \dots}

Some math expressions: $1+1=2$,  $\int_0^1 \mathrm{d}x = 1$
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Mico: Thanks for the answer. Somehow I couldn't install the fonts properly, but I'm sure it'll work fine once I figure out how to install the fonts.

Comment: @KevinC In all the most used TeX distributions everything can be installed with the package manager.

Comment: @KevinC - Which TeX distribution do you use? If you use either TeXLive or MikTeX, obtaining and installing the recently released `newpx[text,math]` packages should be performed automatically when you run the package update scripts.

Comment: @Mico and @Speravir: I use BaKoMa TeX mainly, and MikTeX with TeXWorks to verify/supplement the former. My MikTeX is up to date, and I've installed fonts in BaKoMa according to its user guide. But neither produces the desired output. In particular, TeXWorks+MikTeX keeps telling me that `File 'newpxtext.sty' not found.`

Comment: @KevinC Just a wild guess: [Difference between administrative and user mode of MiKTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67712/difference-between-administrative-and-user-mode-of-miktex).

Comment: @Speravir: There's only one user in my computer, and I updated MikTeX in the admin mode. If I understand things correctly, when I open the MikTeX package manager, I should be able to find a package called `newpx`, right? But I couldn't, and the closest package name I found was `newtx`. However, installing `newtx` doesn't seem to change much. Also, I think there might be a typo in the Readme file of the `newpx[text,math]` package, where it "confuses" between `newpx` and `newtx` in its instruction of installation for MikTeX.

Comment: @KevinC Then change the download mirror or do a new synchronization. It _is_ available as MiKTeX repository. And `newpx` and `newtx` are relatives (both good!), but not the same. For modes: If you back in the past **once** did a update in user mode you **must** also do this **every time** in future!

Comment: @KevinC - I no longer use MikTeX, but when I still used to do so, I remember there being a difference between updating already-installed packages and installing entirely new packages. If you've had MikTeX on your system for more than a month, you'll need to bring up the "Package Manager" program, as the `newpxtext` and `newpxmath` packages -- having been released less than a month ago -- will fall into the new-and-not-yet-installed category.

Comment: @Mico and @KevinC No, it’s just `newpx`, what then contains both mentioned sub-packages.

Comment: @Speravir: Changing the download mirror worked :) Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

*This is more thought as chronicler’s duty after first writing an erroneous answer and searching for cure than as useful addition in regard to the question.*

Beside Mico’s answer:

If you load first `mathpazo` and `tgpagella` second, then `tgpagella` does only overwrite text related definitions of `mathpazo`, but not the maths part.

This at least unexpected behaviour, if not bug, of `tgpagella` to produce oldstyle figures in small caps mode, but lining figures in other modes, can be changed with the help of `newenviron` and `xstring` *(notes below)*:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage{tgpagella}

\usepackage{textcomp} % for "\text...oldstyle" commands

\usepackage{newenviron,xstring}
  \newenviron{osf}{ % automatic definition of "\osfbody"
    \expandarg\StrSubstitute{\osfbody}{1}{\textoneoldstyle}[\osfI]
    \StrSubstitute{\osfI}{2}{\texttwooldstyle}[\osfII]
    \StrSubstitute{\osfII}{3}{\textthreeoldstyle}[\osfIII]
    \StrSubstitute{\osfIII}{4}{\textfouroldstyle}[\osfIV]
    \StrSubstitute{\osfIV}{5}{\textfiveoldstyle}[\osfV]
    \StrSubstitute{\osfV}{6}{\textsixoldstyle}[\osfVI]
    \StrSubstitute{\osfVI}{7}{\textsevenoldstyle}[\osfVII]
    \StrSubstitute{\osfVII}{8}{\texteightoldstyle}[\osfVIII]
    \StrSubstitute{\osfVIII}{9}{\textnineoldstyle}[\osfIX]
  }{
    \expandarg\StrSubstitute{\osfIX}{0}{\textzerooldstyle} %could be set into start code as well!
   }

\begin{document}
\textsc{\TeX\ Gyre Pagella} -- a \textsc{Palatino} clone.

1234567890 glyphs in \TeX\ Gyre Pagella.

\textoneoldstyle\texttwooldstyle\textthreeoldstyle\textfouroldstyle
\textfiveoldstyle\textsixoldstyle\textsevenoldstyle\texteightoldstyle
\textnineoldstyle\textzerooldstyle\ glyphs in \TeX\ Gyre Pagella.

\begin{osf}
1234567890 glyphs in \TeX\ Gyre Pagella (1234567890 times).

$(1 + 2) * 34 - 5 - 6 + 7 - 8 = 90$ %produces warnings
\end{osf}

\scshape
1234567890 Small Caps in \TeX\ Gyre Pagella.

\bfseries
1234567890 Small Caps in \TeX\ Gyre Pagella.

$(1 + 2) * 34 - 5 - 6 + 7 - 8 = 90$
\end{document}
```

[image: example output]

- All TeX Gyre font examples use themselves the `\textcomp` commands for oldstyle figures.
- I used `newenviron` because it can be nested, for the minimal working example probably `environ` would have been enough (cf. [What is the problem with nested environments using \BODY (environ package)?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/101629/what-is-the-problem-with-nested-environments-using-body-environ-package)).
- Note that math mode inside the `osf` environment produces warnings.
- I did not test this, but applying the environment to the whole document should significantly increase the compile time.

Answer (score 2):

In LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX, `fontspec` lets you load any font with the `Numbers=OldStyle` option, and to use the `\oldstylenums` and `\liningnums` commands.  TeX Gyre Pagella should just work out of the box with `\setmainfont[Ligatures={Common,Rare,TeX}, Numbers=OldStyle]{TeX Gyre Pagella}`.  So will any recent OpenType version of Palatino (although some old versions of Palatino Linotype have the bug that small-caps `i` is dotted.)

Then, you can load either Asana Math or TeX Gyre Pagella Math in `unicode-math`.