# Mathpazo old style numbers in text, but lining figures in tables, captions or section headings

Tags: fonts, memoir, oldstylenums

My question is very similar to [lining figures in tables and math, old style figures in text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/114331/lining-figures-in-tables-and-math-old-style-figures-in-text), except I am using the mathpazo font.

I would like to use text figures in the body (through `usepackage[osf]{mathpazo}`), but want to use lining figures for

- equations
- equation number in brackets
- table of contents
- page numbers
- table and figure labels (e.g. the caption: "Fig 1.1: Comparison of ...", I would like "1.1" to use lining figures)
- tables

For various reasons, I need to use `pdftex`.

How can I use `mathpazo` with these requirements? If you have typographical arguments against any of these points, please let me know!

A MWE with only text figures:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb}
\usepackage[osf]{mathpazo}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{Old style numbers}
Old style numbers belong in text 0123456789. Not in in-line equations $\sqrt{4+x^2} = y$
Not in equations:
\begin{align}
    \min_{x,y} &\quad y^2 \\
    \mathrm{s.t} &\quad x > 4\\
        &\quad x < y^2
\end{align}
Nor in tables.

\begin{table}[!htb]
  \caption{mean, median and standard deviation}
  \label{tab:mean}%\libertineTabular
    \begin{tabular}{lccccr}
    \toprule
      climate & species & mean &  median & standard deviation & number of experiments \\
    \midrule
      1 & \textit{Picea abies}  & 20,3699   & 20,0335   & 4,453 & 30 \\
      2 & \textit{Picea abies}  & 23,9864   & 12,6398   & 7,236 & 98 \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\[ a^2 + b^2 = c^2 \qquad 1234567890 \]
Old style numbers belong in text 0123456789.

\section{New section}

\section{Newer section}

\section{Newest section}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I've taken the liberty of adding the `memoir` tag, as this document class has lots of specialized font-handling capabilities.

Comment: Are you free to use the newer `newpxtext` and `newpxmath` packages in lieu of the somewhat-ancient `mathpazo` package?

Comment: @Mico, the OP hasn't manifested themselves on your question. If I may intrude, I would like to hear about `newpxtext` and `newpxmath` in this context.

Comment: @gusbrs - Thanks. I'm still hoping that the OP will choose to address my questions. Let's give him/her a bit more time...

Comment: @Mico, in the meantime I found this https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/109960/105447. I asked because I've been fond of Palatino and clones for quite some time, but had dismissed `newpx` because I like oldstyle figures and the [LaTeX Font Catalogue](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/newpx/) does not even suggest `newpx` includes them. So, thank you for pointing me to that!

Comment: If you’re updating your packages, I’d recommend `unicode-math` with Asana Math as the math font and Palatino (or TeX Gyre Pagella) as the text font, loaded with `Numbers=OldStyle`.  You can then use the method in my answer to switch to lining fixed-width numbers in tables.

Comment: If you’re sticking with legacy Type 1 fonts, don’t forget to call `fontenc` to set the text encoding to either T1 or LY1. Also a good idea to use `microtype`, which supports Palatino and its clones in both Type 1 and OpenType.

Comment: @Mico, thanks for pointing that out. `newpxtext` and `newpxmath` are fine and work with my document

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your MWE already does old-style numerals in text and lining numerals in equations.  That leaves your tables.  Since `mathpazo` uses a Palatino clone as its text font, the easiest way to switch to lining numbers is to switch the font family to a Palatino clone with lining numbers, such as `qplr` for TeX Gyre Pagella.

If you’re using `fontspec` or `unicode-math` (Asana Math is a good OpenType replacement for `mathpazo` and you can use TeX Gyre Pagella as your matching text font, or you can keep using `mathpazo` with `fontspec` or `mathspec`), it gets even easier.  You can get lining, tabular numbers with code like the following example from the `fontspec` manual:

```
{\addfontfeatures{Numbers={Monospaced,Lining}}
\begin{tabular}{@{} cccc @{}}
    Year & People & Miles & Boats \\
    \hline  1842 &  999   &  75   &  13   \\
    1923 &  111   &  54   &  56
\end{tabular}}
```

You can of course encapsulate either macro into something like `\tnums` or even a new table environment, to make it more semantic and less dependent on a specific package.

The `fontspec` package also adds both `\oldstylenums` and `\liningnums` commands that switch the OpenType font features of the currently-selected font.

Bear in mind that using different numerals for text mode and math mode makes it very obvious which mode you’re writing your numbers in.  It’s not clear why `these 4 cases` is different from `x = 4` or which one `x equal to 4` should match.  Most authors prefer to be consistent within the same document, or perhaps use old-style numerals in specific contexts such as headings or dates.

Comment: If the tables float memoir has a system to add thst font change to all floating tables.

Comment: @daleif Wasn’t aware of that. That’s convenient.

Comment: See `\setfloatadjustment` in the `memoir` manual

Comment: Alternative: `\newenvironment` that wraps the table in a font change? Works in standard LaTeX.

Comment: Yes, but bad programming style

Comment: @daleif You could also use the `\newcolumntype` or `>` commands of `array` and `tabularx`. redefine `\tabularxcolumn`command for `tabularx`, or `\LTpre` of `longtable`.

Comment: I would like to stick with pdflatex, so unfortunately using `fontspec` is off the table. Any way to do this without `fontspec`?

Comment: @maero21 I’d suggest switching the font family to `qplr` (TeX Gyre Pagella) in the T1 encoding for tables or table columns containing numbers. Both Pagella and Pazo are clones of the same font, Hermann Zapf’s Palatino, so they’ll match.

Comment: @Davislor Thanks for that. That gets the job done, but then the rest of the text in the table has an ever so slightly different font to the rest of the main text (as @Mico suggested, I am now using `newpxtext` and `newpxmath`).

Comment: @Davislor with `ppl` it looks perfect, so I'll use that. Thanks!